# Adding custom code on flagging a node

Tags: flags

I am using the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module on my site. In which function should I add my custom code that is executed when users click on the flag button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the [Trigger](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger) and the Flag actions modules, you can assign a group of actions that is executed when a user or a node is flagged by a user.
Flag integrates also with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), and it allows to execute rules when a flag is used for users or nodes.